# Linking Error C++

Tags: visual-c++

I am getting the following error during linking c++ code  with MS VC 6:

```
Creating library Debug/RATPSS.lib and object Debug/RATPSS.exp
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib "MSVCRTD" conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

CDispatchFailurePssData.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class ostream_withassign cout" (?cout@@3Vostream_withassign@@A)

CNormalAccPssData.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class ostream_withassign cout" (?cout@@3Vostream_withassign@@A)

CNormalPssData.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class ostream_withassign cout" (?cout@@3Vostream_withassign@@A)

Debug/RATPSS.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
Error executing link.exe.
```

Other thirdparty softwares used: Rouguewave 4,orbix 5.1 .

Please suggest the possible solution approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem of the properties of the project that are dependent on each other.
Probably change the property would fix the problem.

See here [/NODEFAULTLIB (Ignore Libraries)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz4da4a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and change the property according to your requirment.